# Getting the sale amount at a store from last period, given that there are many stores (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Given that I have 3 columns of data as such, where 1st column is *date of sale record*, 2nd column is *store address*, and 3rd is column *sale amount* as following **dataframe** :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['01-01-2011','01-01-2011','01-01-2011','01-07-2011','01-07-2011','01-08-2011'],
                   'Store_Address' : ['1000E, Chicago IL','1000E 67th, Chicago IL','1000 N Central Park Chicago IL',
                                      '1000 A Central Park Chicago IL','1000 B Central Park Chicago IL',
                                      '1000 C Central Park Chicago IL'],
                   'Sales': [1000, 2000, 1500, 3000, 2000, 2500]})

>>> df  

         Date                   Store_Address  Sales
0  01-01-2011               1000E, Chicago IL   1000
1  01-01-2011          1000E 67th, Chicago IL   2000
2  01-01-2011  1000 N Central Park Chicago IL   1500
3  01-07-2011  1000 A Central Park Chicago IL   3000
4  01-07-2011  1000 B Central Park Chicago IL   2000
5  01-08-2011  1000 C Central Park Chicago IL   2500
```

I am interested in creating a column of data that indicates the sale from each store from the last time the sale was recorded. How would you go about doing it?

note: not all sale records are recorded on the same day. some stores do not operate on some months/years.

I was thinking to create a temporary dataframe of each address with the sale, get the previous sale value, combine it back to the main dataframe. repeat the process for all address, then combine these columns to a single column.

Do you have a better way of doing it? Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby('Store_Address')[Sales].last()
```